# Rest Api application can't connect to postgres db in the same Kubernetes pod

Tags: spring, postgresql, kubernetes

Hi i receive the following error:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [file.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to
>   create requested service
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

I have a kubernetes cluster where I defined a pod with two containers, one is the postgres db and the other one is a java rest-api application. I'm unable to connect to the db from the application. I'm tring to connect to the postgres db using spring, this is my xml file configuration:

```xml
<!-- JPA Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.my-package.it.name.db" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <!--<property name="showSql" value="true" />-->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Well thanks for your time and help

Comment: Are you able to connect DB when you start application out of the k8s cluster? With local tomcat for instance

Comment: Hi Nikolay, yes I'm able also to connect a pgAdmin container instance to the DB

Comment: I did mean different. When you launch your Spring app not inside k8s pod, but on your localhost, does it start successfully or fails with same Error?

Comment: If I run it on master localhost it start succesfully

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is, create deployment for your database and then service, which targets this deployment and then ping using this service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

If you want me to reproduce it on your files, please provide it in your post.
You can check this [article](https://blog.nebrass.fr/playing-with-spring-boot-on-kubernetes/).